# Possible options for single language site other than English?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

What are the possible options for having a single language non-English site? I am thinking of performance mostly.

I don’t want prefix or suffix in urls. I don’t preferably want entity language (Language neutral possible in Drupal 8)

Adding a second language, deleting English? Will this have implications?

Answer (score 4):

For a Single Language non English site, When you install Drupal 7, it gives you option of selecting the Language. Plus you will need to download the language PO files for your language.

But if you are using Drupal 8 the only requirement is selecting correct language when you install your Drupal. Drupal 8 will automatically download all the language files for you.

Comment: Thanks, but performance-wise this is no different than adding a second language, and setting it as default. I am searching for a better way if possible.

Comment: May I know what performance considerations you have for this?

Comment: Basically, for every translated string to be rendered, there is a query from the database to get that string translation. I wonder if there is an easy way to overcome this. There is a discussion about the subject here: https://groups.drupal.org/node/149984

Comment: No, that is not true, there isn't a query per string or at least only the first requests. This is cached in a single entry. There is no other way, this is the recommend and more or less only way.